# How to get project classes from inside maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, class, maven-plugin

Now I am developing a maven plugin for our project purposes.
The plugin has parameter **dtoPackage** which is like `"com/blablabla/dto"`. It contains info about where DTO classes are.
Another parameter is **workingDirectory** - compiled classes directory which is like `${project.build.directory}/classes/`.

Then I want to get Class objects from DTO package inside my plugin. What I do:

```
URL[] urls = new URL[]{new URL("file:///" + workingDirectory.concat(dtoPackage))};

ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

Class cls = cl.loadClass(dtoPackage.replaceAll("/", ".").concat(".DtoClassName"));
```

And exception is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blablabla.dto.DtoClassName

What is wrong?

Comment: I think the directory url should not contain the package name, just the root directory where classes are

Comment: Can you please tell the intent as it seems you are trying to achieve run time class loading to plugin

Comment: Thank you, @zapl. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user zapl. There is no need to concatenate the **workingDirectory** string with the **dtoPackage** string. Code below works as planned.

```
URL[] urls = new URL[]{new URL("file:///" + workingDirectory)};

ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

Class cls = cl.loadClass(dtoPackage.replaceAll("/", ".").concat(".DtoClassName"));
```